# Pick image from custom image library [Swift]

Tags: swift, uiimagepickercontroller

I am new to Swift/app development. I have successfully developed an app that uses an UIImagePickerController to let the user select an image from the device's photo library. However, I would like the user to select images from a custom set of images, and not from the device's photo library.

What would be the easiest way to implement this? Any help appreciated!

**Edit**

As per requested here is some of the code I am using.

I have a view controller that adheres to the following protocols:

```
class StockViewController: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate
```

On my main storyboard, I have an UIImageView with a tap gesturer which triggers an action on `selectImageFromPhotoLibrary`.

```
@IBAction func selectImageFromPhotoLibrary(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    // UIImagePickerController is a view controller that lets a user pick media from their photo library.
    // Hide the keyboard.

    let imagePickerController = UIImagePickerController()

    // Only allow photos to be picked, not taken.
    imagePickerController.sourceType = .PhotoLibrary
    imagePickerController.allowsEditing = false

    // Make sure ViewController is notified when the user picks an image.
    imagePickerController.delegate = self

    presentViewController(imagePickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

The only source types I can select for the imagePickerController are SavedPhotoAlbums, Camera or PhotoLibrary. I cannot select any app image folder.

Comment: Are the images pre-set on the app? As in, are the image on the app when you download it?

Comment: Yes, that's the idea, but I don't know how to implement it. I thought all I needed to do was to add the images to the images.xcassets folder.

Comment: Can you post your code? I want to look at the part were you access the photos from the library and were you use them. Another option would be to create a repo on GitHub for the app and post the link.